Using æ, ø and å in \include files
In include files I get error if I use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and
if use \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} get Ã¦. , Ã, and Ã¥ insted of æ, ø and å.

Welcome. // I‘d avoid it and use English alphabet only.

Welcome to TeX.SE.  Are these letters in your file name, or in the file contents?  If the latter, I would be surprised if \include was involved.  Could you make a minimal working example (MWE) that shows your problem?  What operating system are you using?

Welcome! Avoiding å, æ and ø is not so easy if one has them in text. But maybe you can use utf8 for all files?

I am not sure if you are referring to the usage of non-ascii characters in text or in file names...

You never need to use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} as that is the default encoding. You can not use that in a file that is included as \usepackage is a preamble command not for use within the document.
You can use characters æ, ø and å in text in UTF-8 whether they are in the main file or in included files, you do not need to declare UTF-8 encoding.
